# Instantaneously at Rest. What does it mean?

Tags: calculus, physics

What is instantaneously at rest? Does it mean that velocity and acceleration must be both 0?

So for question, $v(t) = 3 - t/2$, $t>4$, why is $t=6$ instantaneously at rest?

Comment: Because $v(6)=0$.  You do not need $a(6)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question is suited for Physics SE, I'll answer it.

We use the term instantaneous velocity to show that the velocity is something at a particular instant (or the smallest amount of time that can be measured).

Here, the function $v(t) = 3 - \frac{t}{2}$ shows how the velocity changes with time. If we put $t=6$, we get that $v(6) = 0$. What does this mean? It means that the velocity of the object at time $6$ is $0$. So, we may say that it is at rest.

For a body to be at rest at an instant doesn't require it to have an acceleration of $0$.